# Liquibase's DbDoc listing all changes as "Pending / Not yet ran"

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase is integrated into our Spring application and the database migration is executed during the application startup phase.

When running DbDoc via the Maven plugin all changes are reported as "Pending Changes (NOT YET RAN)". So I cannot create a diff view for our next release.

The issue I found is that the Spring bean uses the classpath relative path for the changelog entries in the DATABASECHANGELOG table. When running the DbDoc via the Maven plugin the filepath relative to the Maven project's root is used.

The code of the NotRanChangeSetFilter cannot deal with this difference:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/3.3.2/liquibase/changelog/filter/NotRanChangeSetFilter.java

Particularly the following comparison will not work:

```
ranChangeSet.getChangeLog().equalsIgnoreCase(changeSet.getFilePath())
```

The methods return the following values:

```
getChangeLog(): classpath:changelog/5.3.3/nos_add_acp_data.xml
getFilePath(): src/main/resources/changelog/5.3.3/nos_add_acp_data.xml
```

Thus the equalsIgnoreCase comparison fails, which results in all changes being listed as "Pending / NOT YET RAN".

Is there any known work-around? The only solution I can imagine is to provide our own implementation of the NotRanChangeSetFilter and put it on the classpath before the Liquibase Maven plugin gets executed. Are there any other ideas or even an official fix for this?

**Update 2015-04-30:** After a lot of debugging I think that the path in the DATABASECHANGELOG table must be normalized, before it is stored. Additionally each tool must normalize its path as well so that the comparisons work. I found the following places in the code where comparisons fail with the current concept:

- RanChangeSetFilter.getRanChangeSet(): equalsIgnoreCase() comparison
- ValidatingVisitor.visit():  ranIndex.get(changeSet.toString(false));
- NotRanChangeSetFilter.accepts(): equalsIgnoreCase() comparison
- RanChangeSet.isSame(): equalsIgnoreCase() comparison

In the latter there is a single "normalize()" method which strips the classpath: prefix from the path. But that is only in one of the 4 places.

The DbDoc tool seems to be able to work with the source code path relative to the Maven project root and with the classpath path. So there are the following configuration options in a MAven project:

```
<changeLogFile>changelog/complete.xml</changeLogFile> -> "classpath:" prefix is missing in the comparison

<changeLogFile>src/main/resources/changelog/complete.xml</changeLogFile> -> "src/main/resources" is the prefix in the comparisons
```

BTW, the first optiom should be documented in the Maven plugin documentation.

Pull request to make the DbDoc Maven plugin work:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/413

Regards,
     Michael

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the difference is due to the differences in the filepath Liquibase stores. Each changeSet is identified by a combination of id+author+filepath so you need to ensure filepath is consistent across all the ways of running Liquibase.

Usually the best way is to have your changelog files in your classpath and always refer to changelogs using paths relative to the classpath, such as "changelog/5.3.3/nos_add_acp_data.xml".

I'm not sure how you are referencing your files currently. If you are using 3.3.2, there was an issue related to how includeAll works with spring that has been addressed in 3.3.3 that you may be running into.

Otherwise, you can always use the "logicalFilePath" attribute on your root databaseChangeLog node to hard-code what liquibase uses as the path so you always know it will be the same, however it is referenced.

Comment: For mee it seems as if the concept of the path is somewhat broken.

The "classpath:" prefix should be removed from the DATABASECHANGELOG table and the tools that look into this table to find an alreadyx executed changelog need to make sure that the path is normalized.

If I specify <changeLogFile>changelog/complete.xml</changeLogFile> for the DbDoc Maven plugin, the complete.xml seems to be found via the classpath, but the prefix "classpath:" is missing when looking into the table, so all comparisons fail.

Comment: The idea behind including it so that you don't have to worry about unique ids across all your files, just within a file. Spring adds the classpath: prefix which does cause problems, but LIquibase should be handling that in the comparison logic.

Comment: I would suggest making a utility class for comparison and adding all kind of normalization there: "classpath:" prefix removal, "src/main/resources" prefix removal, slash/backslash conversion, ...
Then you could use this Comparator in all places where a comparison is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the pull request. Centralizing the logic is a good idea as well.